# Error preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Tags: php

Error:
Depreciated

> Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead
>
> Reporting File: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\core\Input.php

At Line 704: `$source = preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me',"chr(\\1)", $source);`

Comment: Did you have a question? You can find preg_replace_callback in the PHP manual if you don't know how to use it..

Answer (score -1):

Try using `preg_replace_callback` in conjunction with `preg_replace`for that. The code below shows how... and you may first test it [here](https://eval.in/610499).

```
    <?php
        $ascii      = "&#65;";
        $litChar    = preg_replace_callback('/&#(\d+);/m',  function($matches){
            return chr(preg_replace("/[&#;]/", "", $matches[0]));
        }, $ascii);

        var_dump($litChar);  //<== PRODUCES:: 'A' (length=1)
```